# How to act upon a particular exception in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

I had been a facing a particular exception in C# for example - `"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."`

How can I make sure that a specific routine of correction tasks takes place only at the emergence of this exception? I have been using a work-around by comparing the error message with a predefined string. For example -

```
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        if(e.Message=="...")
        {  
            //correction routine
        }
    }
```

But, this doesn't seem to be the conventional way. Any guideline would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can have multiple catch blocks to do different things based on the type of exception e.g. catch (SqlException sqlEx) { ... }

Comment: At the very least, I *highly* suspect that there's a more specific exception type than `Exception` that is containing this message. E.g. a `System.Net.WebException` maybe?

Comment: filtering the exception by message is not a good idea, as the messages might be localized. Therefore the exception has a different message in a language other than English

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the conventional way *prior to C# 6.0* (other than maybe catching a more specific exception type).  In C# 6.0 you can add exception filters:

```
catch (Exception ex) if (ex.Message.Contains("The underlying connection was closed"))
{
    //correction routine 
}
```

There may be safer means than checking the message, however.  Look at the `ErrorCode` and see if you can't filter on that (since it's not affected by culture).

```
catch (Exception ex) if (ex.ErrorCode == 1234)
{
    //correction routine 
}
```

Comment: I'll definitely give this a try. However, could you please elaborate on how I could check against a specific error code? Thank you.

Comment: @ihayet Added, although I made up the error code - you'll have to determine what error code(s) you're interested in

Comment: @D Stanley Once again, thank you very much. I'll definitely check my error code and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You can chain-together using the actual types of the exception:

```
try
{

}
catch(SpecificExceptionType e) //System.Net.WebException in your case, I think
{
    //Specific exception
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Everything else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the catch to an exception sub-type. **Note**, if you can't handle a caught exception, for whatever reason, you should re-`throw` it.

```
...
catch (SqlException sex)
{
    if(sex.Message == 
        "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.")
    {
        // Handle the exception.
    }
    else
    {
        throw
    }
}
```

if you are using C# 6.0 or later, you can combine the condition with the catch.

```
...
catch (SqlException sex)
    if (sex.Message ==
        "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.")
{
    // Handle the exception.
}
```

Comment: I'd be really disappointed if the sex message were "whatever" :p